# Read JSON variable with point in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize and after several tries to do a Inner Join I achive a good result:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Query not successful, the result was empty",
    "data": {
        "codWO": "1016285246",
        "codType": "01",
        "origin": "1016285246--origin",
        "solution": "1016285246--solution",
        "consecuence": "1016285246--consecuence",
        "actions": "1016285246--actions",
        "hours_stopped": 20.5,
        "failureState": "1016285246--failureState",
        "failureEquipment": "1016285246--failureEquipment",
        "failureEffect": "1016285246--failureEffect",
        "failureCause": "1016285246--failureCause",
        "wo_cor_type.name": "Emergency Repair",
        "wo_cor_type.description": "Urgent repairs such as a broken device that avoid running the test.",
        "wo_cor_type.codType": "01"
    }
}
```

I can read all variables except the last tree, beacuase they have points.

How can I read this kind of variables?

```
    vm.woCorrective = data.data;
    console.log(data.success);
    console.log(vm.woCorrective);
    console.log(vm.woCorrective.codWO);
    console.log(vm.woCorrective.solution);
    console.log(vm.woCorrective.failureCause);
    // console.log(vm.woCorrective.[('wo_cor_type.name')]);
```

Comment: `console.log(vm.woCorrective['wo_cor_type.name'];` For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: cann't you nest the wo_cor_type into a sub object?

Comment: console.log(vm.woCorrective['wo_cor_type.name']; It's perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(vm.woCorrective["wo_cor_type.name"]);
console.log(vm.woCorrective["wo_cor_type.description"]);
console.log(vm.woCorrective["wo_cor_type.codType"]);
```